# Conditional formatting not formatting dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

The conditional formatting is not picking up all dates. The rule should be any which are less than today should be orange.

Any help appreciated

Rule's Formula : `=F3<TODAY()`
Applied to a whole column, but some are orange, and some are not, and some with text (title) are orange...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: From screenshots it seems those are actual excel dates formatted as `UK` regional settings, however it is not reading correctly, one easy way to verify whether those are actually dates or not by selecting the whole column `F` and hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`~` which converts the dates to a number, as in excel dates and times are stored as numbers, if it does then the formula in CF should work, otherwise you need to investigate more whether there is any offending leading or trailing characters or not. Also it would be better to convert the range of data into table and use `CF` which ignores the headers

Comment: As your formatting range is `$F:$F` the rule should read: `=AND(F1<>"",F1<TODAY())`

Comment: Per previous comments, this looks more like a data cleaning exercise rather than a conditional formatting error. Having said that one way to do the data cleaning is by  updating the conditional formula to determine what to do if F3 is (not) a number.

Answer (score 0):

You formatting formula `F3<TODAY()` applied to `$F:$F`, seem to apply format on C `F1`, depending on content of cell `F3`.

You could fix formatting formula with: `=F1<TODAY()`

Your screenshot is very confusing, probably becaus you have a filter on (on column B) and row numbers are not displayed - so we cannot figure how formula is applied.